# Can not find column 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Good morning, I'm having difficulty overcoming this problem that came up when I tried to use a table column through a select in C #. I can fetch the value and put it in text.box3, but the real purpose was to use that value as X in my chart.

The value 4 that appears in the error is one of the values of the column I want to insert. It mean that the query is working it seems that the way I'm using to get these values ​​from the column, is not correct. There is no way to use the query data in a variable? so i can use this variable to insert it into the chart.

This is the exception im getting:

```
  [IndexOutOfRangeException: Não é possível localizar a coluna 4.]
  System.Data.DataColumnCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) +79
  System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointCollection.GetValueType
  (IEnum
  erator enumerator, String field) +918    
  System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointCollection.
  AutoDetectValues
  Type(Series series, IEnumerator xEnumerator, String xField, IEnumerator 
  yEnumerator, String yField) +25
  System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.
  Charting.ChartImage.DataBind(IEnumerable dataSource, ArrayList seriesList) 
  +1089
  System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.
  PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable 
  data) +21 
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.
  OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnume
  rable data) +128
  System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select
  (DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, 
  DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +34
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +114
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) 
  +22
  System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +88
  System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
  System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean           
  includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, 
  Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +883a
```

Here is the code:

```
    String connectionString =
    "Data Source=localhost;" +
    "Initial Catalog=DB_SACC;" +
    "User id=sa;" +
    "Password=1234;";
    decimal average = 0;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    string teste = "SELECT (Consumo_Medio_Real)AS 'cmr' FROM t_faturas";

    cmd.CommandText = teste;

    connection.Open();

    cmd.Connection = connection;

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            average = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["cmr"].ToString());
            TextBox3.Text = average.ToString();
            break;
        }
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Estimativa";
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = average.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: Remove  ' from 'cmr' at your query.

Comment: Why do you need while loop if you break at first iteration?

Comment: If I remove the crm what do I put in the reader place?@Berkay

Comment: it is true i don't need it thanks @Reniuz

Comment: Not cmr, quation marks that surrounds cmr.

Comment: It gives the same error after all the Changes,and thank you all for the help !

Comment: `even though 4 is a column value` where is value 4 and what columns you talking about? Please update the question and put details what is the actual problem.

Comment: it is done @Reniuz

Comment: If you mention some kind of error, please post the exception you getting (mesage, relevant part of stacktrace etc.)

Comment: I think I've already promissed the error, thank you.@Reniuz